# Change the onClick method of a button programmatically?

Tags: android

The button already have a method in xml:

```
android:onClick="playSound"
```

I created the method in the activity:

```
public void playSound (View view){ //code1 }
```

I want when I press the button to change `onClick` to an existing method in activity,

```
public void pauseSound(View view){ //code2 }
```

and when I press the button again I want `onClick` to go back to the original method,

```
public void playSound (View view){ //code1 }
```

Hint: I am using multiple buttons on same method `playSound`

Comment: Simply use a boolean variable as a status holder.

Comment: You can probably use a variable as flag and call the different methods from inside your `playSound`.

Comment: i tried to use boolean before i post my question, but it is'nt dynamically with multiple buttons (like i am using in my app)

Answer (score 4):

Define a variable (`int`/`bool`), use it as a flag and call the methods as and when required.

```
bool flag = 0;

public void playSoundHandler (View view){ 
    if (flag) playSound(view);
    else pauseSound(view);
}

playSound (View view) {
    // Your code
    flag = 1;
}

pauseSound (View view) {
    // Your code
    flag = 0;
}
```

and set `onClick="playSoundHandler"`.

Edit

---

In case you cannot modify your `playSound` method since multiple buttons use it, you can do the following:

```
bool flag = 0;

public void playSoundHandler (View view){ 
    if (!flag) {
        playSound(view);
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        pauseSound(view);
        flag = 0;
    }
}

playSound (View view) {
    // Your code
}

pauseSound (View view) {
    // Your code
}
```

and set `onClick="playSoundHandler"` for that specific button.

Comment: i am using multiple buttons on same method "playSound"
this solution isn't dynamically with multiple buttons

Comment: @boody If you want different flags for different buttons, store a boolean flag array. If you're saying that a lot of buttons are accessing your `playSound()` method and you don't want to change it, then look at the latest edit. If it's none of these, you might need to explain your problem a bit more.